# highlight a text in web view

Tags: iphone

I am using a html page in the web view. I want to track the location of the html page when I tap on the webview.Basically I want to mark the selected text in the html page.Please help me out as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721064/highlite-select-text-in-uiwebview from a few hours ago. Someone with enough rep should kill this one.

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna have to do some javascript injection on the loaded page if it's not your own html. The javascript needs to locate the tap location and change the CSS of the element(s) where the tap occurred to highlight it. You can't do this just from UIWebView alone.

the developer of iCab Mobile (a full-featured iphone web browser) has some good discussions of things they did along those lines.

http://www.icab.de/blog/2009/07/27/webkit-on-the-iphone-part-1/

There's quite a bit involved with stuff like this. You can google around for something like "iPhone hybrid application project". There's a few opensource items out there which would be useful for learning these techniques.

Also for future consideration, it's kind of rude to suggest someone should "help you out as soon as possible".